# Specific axis formatting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am trying to format the axis labels on a matplotlib graph in a very specific way. My code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_matrix = ...
alpha_values = list(np.power([2.0]*20, xrange(-12,8)))
gamma_values = list(np.power([2.0]*20, xrange(-12,8)))

plotted_matrix = plt.matshow(some_matrix)
plt.colorbar()
xtick_marks = np.arange(len(alpha_values))
ytick_marks = np.arange(len(gamma_values))
plt.xticks(xtick_marks,alpha_values)
plt.yticks(ytick_marks,gamma_values)
plt.xlabel('Alpha values',size='small')
plt.ylabel('Gamma values',size='small')
```

As you can see my `x` (alpha's) and `y` (gamma's) labels are all powers of 2. I would like to know if it is possible to display axis as powers of 2, i.e. have labels 2^-1, 2^1, 2^2, ... (if possible, with the power as a proper superscript).

I have tried to write down:

```
y_formatter = plt.ticker.ScalarFormatter('#**2')
plotted_matrix.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
```

But I get the error message `'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'yaxis'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ticker.FuncFormatter` to define the tick labels, and a `ticker.MultipleLocator` to place them.

The error you get is because you are trying to set the tick formatter, on the `AxesImage` returned by `matshow`, not the `Axes` instance. Here we can use the matplotlib object-oriented approach to make things simpler.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

alpha_values = list(np.power([2.0]*20, xrange(-12,8)))
gamma_values = list(np.power([2.0]*20, xrange(-12,8)))

some_matrix = np.random.rand(len(alpha_values),len(gamma_values))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

plotted_matrix = ax.matshow(some_matrix)
fig.colorbar(plotted_matrix)

def tick_format(x,pos):
    # Map range 0-20 to 2^-12 to 2^8
    return "$2^{{ {:.0f} }}$".format(x-12)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(tick_format))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(tick_format))

ax.set_xlabel('Alpha values',size='small')
ax.set_ylabel('Gamma values',size='small')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very similar to what I found.

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained an answer from another source, which consists on defining separately the sequence of powers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_matrix = ...
alpha_values = list(np.power([2.0]*20, xrange(-12,8)))
gamma_values = list(np.power([2.0]*20, xrange(-12,8)))

plotted_matrix = plt.matshow(some_matrix)
plt.colorbar()
alpha_powers = list(xrange(-12,8))
gamma_powers = list(xrange(-12,8))
xtick_marks = np.arange(len(alpha_values))
ytick_marks = np.arange(len(gamma_values))
xtick_format = ['2^{{{0}}}'.format(i) for i in alpha_powers]
ytick_format = ['2^{{{0}}}'.format(i) for i in gamma_powers]
plt.xticks(xtick_marks, xtick_format)
plt.yticks(ytick_marks, ytick_format)
plt.xlabel('$Alpha values$', size='small')
plt.ylabel('$Gamma values$', size='small')
```

The result is the following:

[image]